# product of two sequences

Tags: analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space.
Let $C$ be nonempty,closed and convex subset of $X$.
Let $x_n$ be a convergent sequence in C and $t_n$ a convergent sequence in $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Is it true that  $t_nx_n$ is convergent?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 2):

If $t_n \to l\in \mathbb{R}^+$ and $x_n \to x\in C$ then $t_nx_n\to lx$. Since
$$\left\|t_nx_n - lx \right\|= \left\|t_nx_n - lx_n+lx_n-lx \right\|\le \left\|t_nx_n - lx_n\right\|+\left\|lx_n-lx \right\| \le |t_n-l|\left\|x_n\right\|+|l|\left\|x_n-x \right\|. $$

Comment: The proof isn't really done here, since you still have to worry about controlling the $||x_{n}||$ factor in the first term of your LHS.

Comment: I know, but this term is bounded since the sequence $(x_n)_n$ is convergent.